# Como agregar un array asociativo en otro array

Tags: php, php7

Quiero que al agregar una array nuevo este tenga un nombre asociativo tal como lo tiene el array uno y dos.
así cuando utilice este nuevo arreglo lo pueda llamar por su nombre asociativo y no por el numero indice

```
$array = [
    'uno'=>[11,12,13],
    'dos'=>[21,22,23],
];

$tres = [31,32,33];

array_push($array, $tres);

// resultado ==========================
Array
(
    [uno] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 12
            [2] => 13
        )

    [dos] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21
            [1] => 22
            [2] => 23
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31
            [1] => 32
            [2] => 33
        )

)
```

Imprimió los array pero no como quiero,
yo quiero que el nuevo array agregado tenga un nombre asociativo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplemente haces esto:

```
$array['tres']=$tres;
```

Y se creará en `$array` una nueva clave `tres` con el contenido de `$tres`.

También puedes hacer la asignación directa, así:

```
$array['tres']=[31,32,33];
```

---

### Prueba completa

```
$array = [
    'uno'=>[11,12,13],
    'dos'=>[21,22,23],
];

$tres = [31,32,33];
$array['tres']=$tres;
print_r($array);
```

**Salida:**

```
Array
(
    [uno] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 12
            [2] => 13
        )

    [dos] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21
            [1] => 22
            [2] => 23
        )

    [tres] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31
            [1] => 32
            [2] => 33
        )

)
```